# There is an issue with the arguments passed to the cv2.bitwise_not() function in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

I wrote the following code:
The code aims to remove hair from photos for cancer detection, in the main code the input is an image after Perform median filtering in the RGB color space, Perform morphological bottom-hat filtering on each color , Convert the image to a 3-channel format channel, Convert the image to grayscale and apply thresholding, Perform element-wise multiplication of each color channel with the binary image, Convert the hair regions to grayscale and apply thresholding, Perform element-wise multiplication of the filtered image with the hair mask.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology
from skimage.morphology import square

def hair_filling(image_path):
    # Load the image as a binary grayscale image
    img_binary = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Perform morphological opening on the binary image
    selem = square(3)
    img_open = morphology.binary_opening(img_binary, selem)

    # Remove small objects from the binary image
    img_cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(img_open, min_size=90)

    # Perform harmonic inpainting on the hair regions
    img_hair = cv2.bitwise_not(img_cleaned) ## got error here
    img_filled = cv2.inpaint(img_hair, img_cleaned, 5, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

    return img_filled

image_path = "output_image2.jpg"
output_image = hair_filling(image_path)

if output_image is not None:
    # Save the output image
    cv2.imwrite("output_image.jpg", output_image)`
```

The error message: error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'bitwise_not'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - src data type = 0 is not supported
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

I will provide the first code that gave me the input for the code I provided earlier:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology
from skimage.morphology import disk

def hair_removal(image_path):
    # Read the image as RGB
    img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if img is None:
        print("Failed to load image:", image_path)
        return None

    # Perform median filtering in the RGB color space
    img_filtered = cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)

    # Perform morphological bottom-hat filtering on each color channel
    selem = disk(8)
    img_filtered_channels = []

    for i in range(3):
        img_filtered_channels.append(cv2.morphologyEx(img_filtered[:, :, i], cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, selem))

    # Convert the image to a 3-channel format
    img_filtered_channels = np.array(img_filtered_channels)
    img_filtered_3ch = np.transpose(img_filtered_channels, (1, 2, 0))

    # Convert the image to grayscale and apply thresholding
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_filtered_3ch, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    thresh = int(np.amax(img_gray) * 0.05)
    img_binary = cv2.threshold(img_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Perform element-wise multiplication of each color channel with the binary image
    img_binary_3ch = cv2.cvtColor(img_binary, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    img_hair = np.bitwise_and(img_filtered_3ch, img_binary_3ch)

    # Convert the hair regions to grayscale and apply thresholding
    img_hair_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_hair, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    thresh = int(np.amax(img_hair_gray) * 0.02)
    img_hair_binary = cv2.threshold(img_hair_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Perform element-wise multiplication of the filtered image with the hair mask
    img_hair_binary_3ch = cv2.cvtColor(img_hair_binary, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    img_new = np.bitwise_and(img_filtered_3ch, img_hair_binary_3ch)

    return img_new

image_path = "hh.jpg"
output_image = hair_removal(image_path)

if output_image is not None:
    # Save the output image
    cv2.imwrite("output_image2.jpg", output_image)
```

I tried getting a photo without hair, but got syntax errors